# Shortening an sql query(Using ms access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have started to experiment more with SQL lately and I ran into a small issue. I would like to know if there is a shorter way to describe this query or what I need to read to understand this better. Any help is appreciated, since I don't even know exactly how to describe my issue..

I have 2 tables, each have 4 values.

```
TableOne           TableTwo
One1                Two1
One2                Two2
One3                Two3
One4                Two4
```

Now what I need, is when I select `One1` and `One3` from TableOne and `Two2` and `Two3` from TableTwo for example, that the query result is the records where they are all equal.

So I would get records that include:

```
One1 and Two2
One1 and Two3
One3 and Two2
One3 and Two3
```

My logic thus far was:

```
Where (TableOne = One1 and TableTwo = Two2) 
   or (TableOne = One1 and TableTwo = Two3)
   or (TableOne = One3 and TableTwo = Two2)
   or (TableOne = One3 and TableTwo = Two3)
```

It seems like too much *hardcoding* or so to me. Is there a way to say `Where TableOne is 1 and Tabletwo is either 2 or 3` then add those records and so on?

Hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in`:

```
where TableOne in (One1, One3) and
      TableTwo in (Two2, Two3)
```

This follows the naming convention in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
Where (TableOne = One1 or TableOne = One3) and (TableTwo = Two2 or TableTwo = Two3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I also tried this myself, for some reason it only returned the ones where One1 = Two2.

Comment: Your original query might need some tweaking then, but as for the `where` clause-this is equivalent to the one in your question (just shorter) - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b215/12